# SIGSEGV(segmentation fault) error in dev c++

Tags: c++, dev-c++

when i have run this code in dev i have a segmentation fault. in line "*(ap + j) =      new int[10];"

```
int main(){
    int** ap;
    for(int j=0;j<10;j++){
        *(ap + j) = new int[10];
        for(int k=0;k<10;k++){
            *(*(ap+j) +k) = 1;
        }
    }
return 0;
}
```

Comment: Use STL containers instead of all this.

Comment: I know other ways may work, but I need to run this!

Comment: also... as well as lines of debug (prints or whatever) comments always help :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You never allocate any memory for `ap`. Something like:

```
int** ap;
ap = new int*[10];
```

is what you want.

Answer (score 0):

You are allocating memory for the data but are not allocating memory for the pointer array. It might be enough for you to change the declaration of `ap` to `int* ap[10];`.

Answer (score 0):

In `*(ap + j) = new int[10];` you dereference memory location which is not allocated yet. First you have to allocate variable `ap` itself.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem here is *(ap +j) = new ...

Where you are assigning memory for the location "ap+j", the problem is `ap + j` is not yet a valid memory location because you have not initialized ap. So when you add j to ap you go into uninitialized memory space and therefore get your segmentation fault.